# generic request with linq to entities and Type parameter

Tags: generics, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I want to make a linq to entities generic request

for example

I have

```
public Dictionary<string, bool> IsObjectInBase(Type type)
{
    MyEntityContainer context = new EntityContainer();
    Dictionary<string, bool> isObjectInBaseDico = new Dictionary<string, bool>
    List<AnObject> objectList = callingAMethod(type.ToString());

    foreach(AnObject object in objectList)
    {
        List<T> genericObjectList = context.type.ToList();
        if(genericObject.Count > 0)
        {
            isObjectInDataBaseDico.Add(type.ToString(),true);
        }
    }
    return isAnObjectInDataBaseDico;
}
```

I cannot use the type parameter for my request with the database context, is anyone know if it's possible to make a generic linq to entities request?

Comment: Oh, this looks really complicated. Did you try `IQueryable<T>.Any<T>()`?  ?

Comment: Generic usually means that you pass generic argument in your method. Not passing a type as a parameter.